# python - variable regex group only replacement

Tags: python

I wish to replace the regex match groups with '#' characters.

There will be a variable number of Regex's with a variable number of groups within.

**Only** the values with the regex group(s) should be replaced.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import re

data = """Line1 '4658'
Line2 data 'AAA'\tBBB\t55555
Roach""".splitlines()

# a variable number of Regex's containing a variable number of groups
needles = [ r"Line1 '(\d+)'",
        r"'(AAA)'\t\S+\t(\S+)",
        r"(Roach)" ]

pattern = re.compile('|'.join(needles))

for line in data:

 match = pattern.search(line)

 if (match):

  print(re.sub(match.string[match.start():match.end()], '#' * len(match.string), line))

# current output
"""
############
Line2 data ##########################
#####
"""

# desired output
"""
Line1 '####'
Line2 data '###' BBB #####
#####
"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the code like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import re

data = """Line1 '4658'
Line2 data 'AAA'\tBBB\t55555
Roach""".splitlines()

# a variable number of Regex 's containing a variable number of groups
needles = [r "Line1 '(\d+)'",
    r "'(AAA)'\t\S+\t(\S+)",
    r "(Roach)"
]

pattern = re.compile('|'.join(needles))

for line in data:
  match = pattern.search(line)
  for matched_str in match.groups():
    if (matched_str):
      line = re.sub(matched_str, '#' * len(matched_str), line)
  print(line)
```

And when ran:

```
$ python a.py
Line1 '####'
Line2 data '###'    BBB #####
#####
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `re.search()` for an extra match. You just need to change your regexes so that they can match all parts of your string then use a proper function to replace the intended parts.

Here is an example for one of the sentences:

```
In [51]: def replacer(x):                                     
             matched = x.groups()
             if len(matched) == 4:
                 return "{}{}{}{}".format(matched[0], len(matched[1]) * '*', matched[2], len(matched[3]) * '*')
   ....:     

In [52]: pattern = re.compile(r"([^']*)'(AAA)'(\t\S+\t)(\S+)")

In [53]: pattern.sub(replacer, "Line2 data 'AAA'\tBBB\t55555")
Out[53]: 'Line2 data ***\tBBB\t*****'
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import re

data = """Line1 '4658'
Line2 data 'AAA'\tBBB\t55555
Roach""".splitlines()

# a variable number of Regex's containing a variable number of groups
needles = [ r"(Line1 )'(\d+)'",
        r"([^']*)'(AAA)'(\t\S+\t)(\S+)",
        r"(Roach)" ]


def replacer(x):                                     
    matched = x.groups()
    if matched[2]:
        # in this case groups from 3rd index have been matched
        return "{}{}{}{}".format(matched[2], len(matched[3]) * '#', matched[4], len(matched[5]) * '#')
    elif matched[0]:
        # in this case groups from 1st index have been matched
        return "{}{}".format(matched[0], len(matched[1]) * '#')
    elif matched[-1]:
        # in this case last group has been matched
        return len(matched[-1]) * '#'


pattern = re.compile('|'.join(["{}".format(i) for i in needles]))


for line in data:
    print(pattern.sub(replacer, line))
```

output:

```
Line1 ####
Line2 data ###  BBB #####
#####
```